# Unable to use the value in a dictionary in one Django view in another Django view (AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'session')

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-sessions, django-request

I am new to using Django. I have a function in views.py that computes the profit and prints it to a webpage in Django. I store the profit in a dictionary by the name of `context` and then store it in a session:

```
#We want to calculate hourly profit  
def profitmanagement(request):
    #Profit has already been computed
    context={'TotalHourlyProfit':TotalProfit} 
    #We will pass this dictionary to our ProfitManagement.html template. This will display our total profit.
    request.session['context'] = context #Save the dictionary using a session to use in another function
    return render(request,"ProfitManagement.html",context)
```

Now I have another function in views.py that will be triggered every hour using APScheduler. It should set the  `TotalHourlyProfit` to zero, and then output it to the webpage. It is as given below:

```
#Sets the hourly profit to zero at each hour 
def ClearHourlyProfit():
       context = request.session.get('context') #Loads the dictionary computed in profitmanagement().  This is returning an error
       context['TotalHourlyProfit']=0 #Set the hourly profit to zero.
       #print("Hourly profit function has context:",context)
       return render(request,"ProfitManagement.html",context)
```

It returns the error:
`AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'session'`

Is there a way by which I can pass the changed value of `TotalHourlyProfit` to my webpage? I will be very grateful to anyone who can point me in the right direction.

**Edit:**

Upon request, I am including the traceback error before request is passed as a parameter and after request is passed as a parameter:

**Before request:**

```
Job "ClearHourlyProfit (trigger: interval[0:00:10], next run at: 2023-02-04 13:58:07 PKT)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\taimo\Documents\Visual Studio Code Workloads\Eziline Project\web_project\POS\views.py", line 93, in ClearHourlyProfit
    context = request.session.get('context') #Loads the dictionary computed in profitmanagement().  This is returning an error
AttributeError: module 'urllib.request' has no attribute 'session'
```

**After request:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\taimo\Documents\Visual Studio Code Workloads\Eziline Project\web_project\POS\apps.py", line 9, in ready
    scheduler.start()
  File "C:\Users\taimo\Documents\Visual Studio Code Workloads\Eziline Project\web_project\scheduler\scheduler.py", line 13, in start
    scheduler.add_job(func=views.ClearHourlyProfit, trigger='interval', seconds=10) #Running this function every hour.
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\apscheduler\schedulers\base.py", line 438, in add_job
    job = Job(self, **job_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\apscheduler\job.py", line 49, in __init__
    self._modify(id=id or uuid4().hex, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\apscheduler\job.py", line 180, in _modify
    check_callable_args(func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\taimo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\apscheduler\util.py", line 391, in check_callable_args
    raise ValueError('The following arguments have not been supplied: %s' %
ValueError: The following arguments have not been supplied: request
```

Comment: The call to `ClearHourlyProfit` doesn't come from the client, is that correct? How can you access the user session if the user doesn't make the request?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want it to be done by the program whenever an hour passes.

Comment: Think you need to store this data somewhere else that is accessible without a request, can you store it in the DB or in a cache?

Comment: I can access it from the DB, yes. However, then I will have to perform the computations already performed in `profitmanagement()`, and I don't want to repeat the code again and again, since I have 4 other similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `request` as an argument in `ClearHourlyProfit()` function as well since it is a view function and also use `{}` empty dict if `context` does not exist so:

```
def ClearHourlyProfit(request):
    context = request.session.get('context', {})
    context['TotalHourlyProfit']=0
    request.session['context'] = context
    return render(request,"ProfitManagement.html",context)
```

Comment: I have tried this, it returns the error: `raise ValueError('The following arguments have not been supplied: %s' %
ValueError: The following arguments have not been supplied: request`

Comment: @MuhammadTaimoor Can you edit the question with the full error traceback after and before using `request`?

Comment: I have tried this as well, it still returns the same issue. I have edited the question to include the traceback as well, please have a look at it.

Comment: @MuhammadTaimoor Did you also include the `ClearHourlyProfit` in urls.py?

Comment: Yes, I have: `path('ProfitManagement',views.ClearHourlyProfit,name='ProfitManagement')`